# Google Cloud Windows VM RDP(tcp) port change not working

Tags: networking, tcp, google-cloud-platform, window, rdp

In the Google cloud platform, I have windows VM to which I want to make a remote desktop connection, it works if I connect with the default port when a VM is created, but if I change a port to something else (like I tried 3300, 3388) from either cloud console or even from **regedit** and restarted the instance, RDP stopped working. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the GCP [firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls), you would have to open the port from the instance (Windows firewall). I assume you can not access the instance anymore. As such, you can use a startup script by [editing the instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#startupscriptrunninginstances) and add a [metadata key](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_a_startup_script_for_windows_instances) and value.

Similar to this [Microsoft blog example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/timomta/2016/11/04/how-do-i-open-ports-with-powershell/), you may use this key “windows-startup-script-ps1” with this Powershell script value

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port  3300" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport= 3300
```

Then, reboot (reset instance).

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the new port to the Firewall rules? Incoming ports are blocked by default, if you want to use a new port you have to add it to the rule below VPC-Networking

Comment: yes..I added it under the firewall rules of the Google cloud instance management screen.

Comment: If you are running Windows Firewall: Did you add the new port to the Windows firewall?

Comment: I did not enable any firewall, I just created VM with default settings